# Heatmap color key with five different colors

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following code and not sure how to use it to display a heatmap with a color key displaying five different colors representing defined values:

```
hm <- heatmap.2(data_matrix, scale="none",Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col = rev(brewer.pal(11,"RdBu")),margins=c(5,5),cexRow=0.5, cexCol=1.0,key=TRUE,keysize=1.5, trace="none")
```

Color key required:

```
<0.3 (blue)

0.3-1 (green)

1-1.3 (yellow)

1.3-3.0 (orange)

>3.0 (red)
```

I would be happy if someone can help. Thanks!

James

Comment: It is R. I'm not sure he is permited to edit or comment with rep 1...

Comment: @JohanLundberg I don't believe those rep limits apply to your own questions (or answers on your own questions).

Comment: As an aside, I didn't recognize the `heatmaps.2` function, so I searched for it on [RSeek](http://rseek.org). The [first hit](http://www.r-bloggers.com/heatmaps-controlling-the-color-representation-with-set-data-range/) probably would have answered your question.

Comment: @joran, I think for comments they do...

Comment: @JohanLundberg No, they [dont't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
require(gplots)
require(RColorBrewer)

## Some fake data for you
data_matrix <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 3.5), 10, 10)

## The colors you specified.
myCol <- c("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red")
## Defining breaks for the color scale
myBreaks <- c(0, .3, 1, 1.3, 3, 3.5)

hm <- heatmap.2(data_matrix, scale="none", Rowv=NA, Colv=NA,
                col = myCol, ## using your colors
                breaks = myBreaks, ## using your breaks
                dendrogram = "none",  ## to suppress warnings
                margins=c(5,5), cexRow=0.5, cexCol=1.0, key=TRUE, keysize=1.5,
                trace="none")
```

This should work, and give you some ideas of how to edit it further if you'd like. To get the legend with your exact values, I wouldn't bother with the built-in histogram and would instead just use `legend`:

```
hm <- heatmap.2(data_matrix, scale="none", Rowv=NA, Colv=NA,
                col = myCol, ## using your colors
                breaks = myBreaks, ## using your breaks
                dendrogram = "none",  ## to suppress warnings
                margins=c(5,5), cexRow=0.5, cexCol=1.0, key=FALSE,
                trace="none")
legend("left", fill = myCol,
    legend = c("0 to .3", "0.3 to 1", "1 to 1.3", "1.3 to 3", ">3"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, shujaa. Somehow the colors in the color key did not match values as expected; the yellow color did not appear at all in the color key.

Comment: Thank you very much, Shujaa. That was the perfect solution. legend() worked perfectly for my needs. Your help was very much appreciated!!!